# How to use only the final values in recursion?

Tags: c++

I am developing a program that converts z3 expressions to qdimcas format. 
The code below prints the qdimacs format code into a file.

here the variable clause_count get modified every time a function is called. 
Is there a way I can use only or print only the final value of clause_count?

```
#include<iostream>
#include "z3++.h"
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
using namespace z3;
using namespace std;



int dimacs(int t, string oprt, int arg_num,int element[],int variables)
{   int static clause_count = 0;
    int static check =0;
     std::cout<<"Value of T is: "<<t<<" operator is: "<<oprt<<" Nuumber of arguments: "<<arg_num<<endl;

     if(arg_num==2)
        std::cout<<element[0]<<" "<<element[1]<<endl;
     else
        std::cout<<element[0]<<endl;        

     ofstream myfile;
     myfile.open("contents.txt",ios::app);
     myfile.clear();

     if(check == 0)
       { 
         myfile<<"p cnf \n";
         check++;
       }
     if(arg_num == 2)
    {   clause_count+=3;
        if(oprt.compare("and")==0)
        {
            myfile<<"-"<<t<<" "<<element[0]<<" 0 \n";
            myfile<<"-"<<t<<" "<<element[1]<<" 0 \n";
            myfile<<"-"<<element[0]<<" -"<<element[1]<<" "<<t<<" 0 \n";
            myfile.close();
            std::cout<<"printing done for AND.\n";
        }
        else if(oprt.compare("or")==0)
        {
            myfile<<t<<" -"<<element[0]<<" 0 \n";
            myfile<<t<<" -"<<element[1]<<" 0 \n";
            myfile<<"-"<<t<<" "<<element[0]<<" "<<element[1]<<" 0 \n";
            myfile.close();
            std::cout<<"printing done for OR.\n";
        }
        else if(oprt.compare("=>")==0)
        {
            myfile<<"-"<<t<<" -"<<element[0]<<" 0 \n";
            myfile<<"-"<<t<<" "<<element[1]<<" 0\n";
            myfile<<"-"<<element[1]<<" -"<<t<<" "<<element[0]<<" 0 \n";
            myfile.close();
            std::cout<<"printing done for implies.\n";
         }

    }  
    else if(arg_num == 1)
    {   clause_count+=2;
        if(oprt.compare("not")==0)
        {
            myfile<<"-"<<t<<" -"<<element[0]<<" 0\n";
            myfile<<t<<" "<<element[0]<<" 0 \n";
            myfile.close();
            std::cout<<"printing done for NOT.\n";
        }
    }  
    std::cout<<clause_count<<endl;
    std::cout<<variables<<endl;
}
```

I basically need to store only the final value of clause_count and pass it to another function.

there is actually another file that calls this function and that file runs the recursion. And withing the recursive calls this dimacs function is called and the parameters are passed through it. 
At the end the dimacs file prints the output whenever this function is called the output is supposed to be something like this:

```
p cnf 3 4
1 2 0
2 1 0 
2 4 0
4 5 0
```

here with the line "p cnf" there are 2 values ie. 3 and 4 where 4 has to be stored in the variable clause_count in my program. But due to recursion I am printing every value of clause_count. I just need the final value.

Comment: I don't understand, returning `clause_count` is not enough ?

Comment: the title is a bit misleading as theres no recursion in this code

Comment: dimacs claims it returns int but fails to do so.

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope this has more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using static variables (which basically are global ones only visible in dimacs) I suggest moving the
static clause_count declaration to a global variable declaration outside the function.

Comment: But is that going to help? I just need to print only the final value of clause_count.